# Safari Extension for right click menu: Open in Google Chrome?

Tags: safari, google-chrome, safari-extensions, adobe-flash

Is it possible for an extension to add items to the right click menu in Safari?  If you enable developer mode, there is a menu item called "Open Page With..." and Google Chrome is a choice if it's installed.  Can the Open Page With... menu get added to the right click menu, so I can use one less step when viewing a page in Chrome?  Right now I'm required to load the page in safari, then choose the Chrome option, whereas I'd rather just right click on links and send them to Chrome quickly.

I would make it myself if I knew how!

Comment: why not assign the menu item to a keyboard shortcut? it'd be more convenient and faster

Comment: Didn't think of that, will have to experiment.  It will still require clicking a link to load the page in safari first

Comment: found this link but it doesn't work: http://projects.skurfer.com/posts/2011/chrome_shortcut/

Comment: Does someone know how to do this with new "Shortcuts" app on macOS Monterey?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### Open in Chrome Service

You can make a Service in 10.6 or 10.7 using Automator that will open a selected URL in Chrome.

Here's how:

1. Open **Automator** [image: Automator Icon]
2. When Automator asks you to **Choose a type for your document** window, select **Service** [image: Service Icon]
3. Change the "Service receives selected" drop-down to "URLs" [image: Service options]
4. Add a **Run AppleScript** action (found under the Automator Library, or just search) by dragging from the left pane to the right
5. Copy the code below to the text field (replacing *all* the existing text)
6. **Save** and give the service a name (it will be added automatically to the services menu)

Code:

```
on run {input}
    set theURL to input
    tell application "Google Chrome"
        if not (exists first window) then
            make new window
            set URL of last tab of first window to theURL
        else
            tell first window
                set newTab to make new tab with properties {URL:theURL}
            end tell
        end if
        activate
    end tell
end run
```

This will open any selected URL in Safari or other application in Chrome, either in a new tab in the most recent window, or a new window if there is no open Chrome window. To access it, right-click and under the Services item at the bottom of the menu, you should see an item with the name you assigned.

*One important caveat*: OS X seems to be a bit picky/buggy about passing link to this sort of service. It works fine if you have text selected as a URL, but it only seems to work on some links. If I discover a better method, I'll update this post with it.

You may also need to restart Safari for the service to appear.

Comment: Thank you, this works for me.  Now if you could tell me how to get that service to the very top of the list, because it's in the middle, and you're right, on some links it doesn't appear.  If I right click your username I can see it, but if I right click my username the option is not available.  Weird

Comment: Yeah, I can't figure out the rhyme or reason to how it responds to links (I suspect it's just buggy behaviour). To change the order in the menu, you could re-save it with a space or special character in the name so that it would at least pop to the top of the sub-menu. I don't know of any way to get it out of the Services sub-menu however.

Comment: Can I use your script to open just Facebook links in for example in Facebook app on Mac?

Answer (score 4):

RobMathers answer works well for me.  You can add a bit to it so you don't have to select the URL.

In Automator, revise his step 3 to "Change the "Service receives selected" drop-down to "no input" "

Then, before adding the "Run AppleScript" with his code, drag "Get Current Webpage from Safari" over from the Internet category in the Automator library.  It will pass the URL to the AppleScript code.  And then you can assign a keyboard shortcut too

Here is the screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Brilliant! This works great.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to bump this old item, but I was looking for a solution and came up with this one that is working great for me.

Want to open the active webpage in a browser other than Safari on your Mac?

It's simple if you have the developer mode enabled.

1. Go to Settings - Keyboard - Keyboard Shortcuts tab
2. Click the + to add a shortcut.
3. Select Safari on the Application drop-down
4. Copy the Menu Title letter for letter from Safari's Develop -> Open Page With menu. 
   "
   Examples: on my machine, Chrome = Google Chrome (22.0.1215.0) — /Applications", Firefox = "Firefox (13.0.1)"

Note: you will have to update this when updating any of the browsers. The developer menu ties the menu options to the version number reported by the Finder.

1. Select your own keyboard shortcut for the alternate browser. I use control+option+command+browser first letter, so Google Chrome = G. I used F for Firefox and O for Opera. control+option+command is not the default for any Safari features as far as I know (for any letter)...
2. From any Safari page, simply push the keyboard shortcut and the page will open in the desired browser.

Enjoy!
E

Comment: problem with this is Chrome version changes pretty quick so you will have to modify your shortcut frequently which is not so convenient.

Answer (score 0):

You can open the current tab in Google Chrome with a Keyboard shortcut.

This uses macOS keyboard settings to add a shortcut to the `Develop - Open Page With - ...` setting, but there are caveats: you may need to update this occasionally when Chrome versions change.

1. In `Safari Preferences – Advanced`, enable `Show Develop menu in menu bar`
2. Now, try the menu and note down (or take screenshot) of the Google Chrome text in `Develop – Open Page With - Google Chrome (version number)`
3. In `System Preferences – Keyboard – Shortcuts`, add a shortcut for this option as follows:

   - Select `App Shortcuts` on left and Click `+`
   - Select `Application – Safari`. For Menu Title, put in the above Google Chrome text exactly as noted, such as **Google Chrome.app (version)**
   - Add your Keyboard Shortcut and click Add
4. It should work immediately. Check the menu in Safari to see if the shortcut appears there. Make sure the text is copied exactly

Tested on macOS Big Sur 11.6. Did *not* work in macOS Monterey 12.1 (even if shortcut appeared in menu).